# Need help with Shallow Water Ripples effect in XNA

Tags: xna, shader, hlsl

I need to create a water-like surface in XNA, viewed from above.
Like this :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nr42AG1aPAY

Can someone point me to some examples?
I don't know where to start.
Thanks,
SW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common request which is demonstrated for most programming environments. You can find lots of resources online by simply doing a search for water ripple shader:
http://www.bing.com/search?q=water+ripple+shader

You'll probably find lots of non-xna versions ([for example](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/samples.html#WaterInteraction)), but if it's an hlsl shader it should be simple to port it to xna since it supports those directly on both windows and the xbox.

Comment: This is awesome - thanks for pointing me in the right direction